# How to describe something that you don't want, but appears?

Tags: word-choice

Context: A girl does not like red. She removes her red garden. But the colour red, wether she likes it or not, appears in her dreams. She has no control of her dreams.

Comment: Only word I can think of is *nightmare*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may choose one of:

- **[Unavoidable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unavoidable)**
- **[Inevitable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inevitable)**
- **[Ineluctable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ineluctable)**

or probably a more relevant wrod to your case:

- **[Inescapable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inescapable)**

Answer (score 1):

Describing the red color as ***undesired*** seems appropriate to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think **unwelcome** could also work...

Answer (score 1):

she was **haunted** by the colour red.

according to merriam-webster

> haunt
>
> of a ghost : to visit or live in (a place)
>
> to keep coming back to the mind of (someone) especially in a way that
>   makes the person sad or upset

Comment: Maybe you could add a relevant definition for "haunted"?